# How do I install a node module in meanio project?

Tags: express, npm, mean.io

I have created a new project with mean and now I am stumped on how to propery integrate a new node module  (lodash).  I have installed the node module `npm install lodash --save` and I see that it has added it to the package.json file and the assets are in the root node_modules folder.

How do I actually use it in my project??

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash without installing it. Because mean.io already has lodash used in it's core part.

If you means your own package, you can `npm install` in your package directory(with its own package.json). Each time other's `mean install` your package, it will install all the modules.